# Running shell job on remote server, closing terminal without closing job

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, torque

I am running jobs on a remote server using torque. I currently have a an annoying problem.

When I run my jobs this is what I currently do:

1. Log into another computer via Teamviewer
2. From that computer `ssh` into the remote server as so `ssh user@remoteserver.com`
3. Here i run my job script `sh verycomplicatedrunscript.sh` which echos to the user something like:

   `I am now running job 1...`

   `I am now running job 2...`

   `I am now running job 3...`

   `I am now running job 4...`

just to show that it is running and what it is running.

Only problem is that this takes several days as the jobs are somewhat large and there are thousands of them.

Now, I would like to bypass the Teamviewer step and just `ssh` into the remote from my own computer. But if I do that, and run my jobs script, and then close the terminal; it kills the process (hence why I am currently running it on the other computer which I can just leave running for days by leaving the terminal open).

Is there any way in which I can execute the script on the remote server, and then logout without it killing the execution of my jobs script?

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

I ended up using the `screen` option which is quite frankly amazing.

My jobs are now running with

`screen sh awesomejobscript.sh option1 option2 option3`

Comment: Run it under `screen` then detach and close ssh.

Comment: This https://wiki.harvard.edu/confluence/display/USERDOCS/How+to+use+'screen'+for+remote+shell+sessions ?

Comment: Yep, but this is more user-friendly, if you want the lazy man way, you'd run like this: `screen ./script.sh` then CTRL+A+D to detach, and when you want to get back at it, `screen -r` or if running multiple screen sessions, save the PID (or the start of it on your head) and `screen -r PID`

Comment: BTW, I don't think this belongs to stackoverflow, this sounds more of unix.stackexchange or superuser.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll take a look at it and I've flagged the question for migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use nohup:

```
$ ssh user@remoteserver.com "nohup complexscript.sh > mylog 2>&1 &"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions it turns out, in addition to the one above;

```
screen sh jobscript.sh op1 op2 op3
```

works very well too.